# Using the Scanf function for inputs for different lengths

Tags: arrays, c, input, scanf

I want to use the scanf function to get inputs that are either two numbers, or one number from the user and put them in an array. However, I'm not sure how I can use this same function to get inputs for both one element of the array, and also two elements of the array.

i.e. if the user enters, 9 0, it should be able to successfully store that in an array and move onto new code, or if the user enters something like 1, it should also be able to successfully store that in the array, and move onto new code.

I've tried putting the scanf into a while loop:

```
int scanned_array[2] = {};
int element = 0;

while(scanf("%d", &scanned_array[element]) {
    //... more code here which will have different functions depending on the input...
    element++;
}
```

How can I successfully do this while only using the scanf function, while loops, arrays and if statements?

****Edit:** Just wondering, if I changed my code according to what was suggested below by @nmgari, how could I go to if(num == 1) { ... without having to press ctrl+d?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A separate scan for whitespace could be used.
The scanset `%1[ \t\r\n]` will capture whitespace character by character. The loop will exit on non-whitespace or a newline.
Then try to scan an integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( void) {
    char space[2] = "";
    int scanned = 0;
    int scanned_array[2] = { 0};

    while ( 1) {
        while ( 1 == scanf ( "%1[ \t\r\n]", space)) {
            if ( '\n' == space[0]) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if ( '\n' == space[0]) {
            break;
        }
        if ( 1 != scanf ( "%d", &scanned_array[scanned])) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "bad input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        ++scanned;
        if ( 2 <= scanned) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for ( int each = 0; each < scanned; ++each) {
        printf ( "%d\n", scanned_array[each]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor: `scanf ( "%1[ \t\r\n]" ...` covers most common white-spaces, but not all.  Could use `getchar(), isspace(), unget()` to handle all WS.

Comment: `space[]` is better re-zeroed before the `scanf ( "%1[ \t\r\n]",...` call to not inherit prior data.  Note `if ( '\n' == space[0])` may be true when the prior `scanf ( "%1[ \t\r\n]...` return EOF due to rare input error.  Best not to use `'\n' == space[0]` unless `scanf ( "%1[ \t\r\n] ...` returned 1.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you want to call scanf() once and read either one number or two.

Something like this should work:

```
int scanned_array[2];
int num_input = 0;

num_input = scanf("%d %d", &scanned_array[0], &scanned_array[1]); 

if(num_input == 1)
{
    //Do something
}
else if (num_input == 2)
{
    //Do somethine else
}
```

Anyway, you need to consider that the second element in the array may never get a value.

Comment: Ok thank you! just wondering, if the second element in the array never gets a value, how would you get it to progress to 
`if (num_input == 1)`

`{`

    `//Do something`

`}`

without using control-d?

Comment: This code will force 2 inputs and only return 1 if the second is not an integer or if end of file occurs after the first integer. `scanf()` will not return until one or the other, possibly spread across multiple lines.

Comment: `"%d %d"` fails if the line of input has only one number as `scanf()` will attempt to read 2 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the input line with `fgets()` and parse it with `sscanf()`:

```
    char buf[120];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        int i1, i2;
        switch (sscanf(buf, "%d%d", &i1, &i2)) {
          case 2:
            /* the user entered 2 integers */
            handle_2_integers(i1, i2);
            break;
          case 1:
            /* the user entered a single integer */
            handle_1_integer(i1);
            break;
          default:
            /* the user did not enter a number */
            handle_invalid_input();
            break;
        }
    } else {
        /* the input stream is at end of file or encountered an error */
        handle_end_of_file();
    }
```

If you run `scanf("%d%d", &i1, &i2)`, `scanf()` will keep reading the input stream until either end of file, or 2 integers have been read or an character has been input that cannot be converted to an integer, possibly reading multiples lines of input for one of these cases to occur. If you want to handle a **single line** of input, you cannot use `scanf()` directly.